# Trying to add an IF statement to an array of objects in Google Apps Script for Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to send an email to a list in a Google Sheet, but only if column N gets marked "Yes." Acceptable data in column N is "Yes" or "No" so I want to test that and send emails only to the rowData that contain "yes" there. Then write the date in the adjacent column on the same row. I can't seem to figure out how to iterate through the array of objects and couldn't find any good resources to explain this. Help greatly appreciated. My best effort was emailing all the rows and then also filling in the date no matter what was in column N (Yes/No/Blank).

```
function sendEmails() {

  validateMySpreadsheet() //a function that checks for "Yes" in column N

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 16);
  var d = new Date();
  var dd = d.getDate();
  var mm = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
  var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
  var date = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy;
  var needsaYes = "Yes";



  //Gets the email template
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
  var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  // Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
   objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

  //This is where I am stuck - how to check if column N contains a "Yes" before allowing the MailApp.SendEmail command to run.

  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
    var rowData = objects[i];
    var values = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; ++j) {
      var row = values[j];
      var checkFirst = row[13]; //row J, Column N?
      if (checkFirst = needsaYes) { //does column N contain "Yes"?
      var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
        var emailSubject = "mySubject";
        MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.email, emailSubject, emailText);
        dataSheet.getRange(2 + i, 15).setValue(date); //then write the date
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }   

    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I needed to just use the .getValues() method for my data range rather than the whole sheet and also remove the unnecessary second for loop:

```
var rowData = objects[i]; var checkData =  ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();  
var row = checkData[i]  
var colN = row[13] if (colN == needsaYes) { //etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check whole code but
`if (checkFirst = needsaYes)`
It may be the problem, you need to use `==`

Comment: you then need to use the apps script debugger and figure out the issue or get more data. this answer already fixes a major bug.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @ZigMandel